# What does it mean for an ODE to be conservative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What does it mean for an ODE to be conservative?

For example, I already read somewhere that the equation
$$w\cdot y''-y+y^{2k+1}=0,$$
with $w>0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ constants fixeds, is conservative. In practice, what does this mean?

Comment: Is $w$ a constant or a variable?  Perhaps the independent variable?

Comment: Is a constant fixed.

Comment: Do you mean a conservative system?

Comment: No, ODE conservative. But, what means conservative system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the differential equation

$wy'' - y + y^{2k + 1} = 0, \tag 1$

we may multiply it through by $y'$:

$wy'y'' - yy' + y^{2k + 1}y' = 0, \tag 2$

and observe that

$\left ( \left ( \dfrac{w}{2} y' \right )^2 \right )' = wy''y', \tag 3$

and

$\left ( -\dfrac{y^2}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2k + 2}}{2k + 2} \right )' = - yy' + y^{2k + 1}y'; \tag 4$

then (2) may be written

$\left ( \left ( \dfrac{w}{2} y' \right )^2 \right )' + \left ( -\dfrac{y^2}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2k + 2}}{2k + 2} \right )' = 0, \tag 5$

or

$\left ( \left ( \dfrac{w}{2} y' \right )^2 -\dfrac{y^2}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2k + 2}}{2k + 2} \right )' = 0; \tag 6$

thus,

$\left ( \dfrac{w}{2} y' \right )^2 -\dfrac{y^2}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2k + 2}}{2k + 2} = C, \; \text{a constant} \tag 7$

along the solution curves $(x, y(x))$ of (1).  That is, the quantity on the left of (7) is a conserved quantity of the equation(1); hence we deem (1) a *conservative* ordinary differential equation, since the function

$F(y, y') = \left ( \dfrac{w}{2} y' \right )^2 -\dfrac{y^2}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2k + 2}}{2k + 2} \tag 8$

is invariant in value on the solution curves.

In general, a conservative second-order equation or system is one for which a function such as $F(y, y')$ exists.  For these $F(y, y')$, it follows that

$\dfrac{\partial F(y, y')}{\partial y} y' + \dfrac{\partial F(y, y')}{\partial y'}y'' = \dfrac{dF(y, y')}{dx} = 0, \tag 9$

and thus $y(x)$ satisfies the deifferential equation (9).  We may in fact invoke these principles to construct differential equations corresponding to many different $F(y, y')$; for example, if

$F(y, y') = \cos y + e^{y'}, \tag{10}$

then we have

$- y' \sin y + e^{y'}y'' = 0, \tag{11}$

or

$y'' = e^{-y'}y'\sin y. \tag{12}$

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno:  my pleasure, sir; and thanks for the "acceptance".  Cheers!